# Finite generation of Tate cohomology groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $F$ be a complete resolution for $G$.  In other words, $F$ is an acyclic chain complex of projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules together with a map $\varepsilon:F_0\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varepsilon:F_+\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$.

It can be shown that we may construct a complete resolution for $G$ in such a way that each $F_n$ is finitely generated.  Such a resolution is said to be of finite type.

If $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, we can define the Tate cohomology groups of $G$ with coefficients in $M$ as follows:

$$\hat{H}\,^n(G,M):=H^n(\mathrm{Hom}_G(F,M))$$

This definition is independent of choice of resolution $F$ because any two choices are homotopy equivalent.

Now, let $M=\mathbb{Z}$ be the trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module.  Using what I've written down, I'd like to see why $\hat{H}\,^n(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is a finitely generated abelian group for all $n$.  I know that in this case $\mathrm{Hom}_G(F_n,\mathbb{Z})\cong F_n^G$ is the group of invariants of $F_n$, so that we are considering the abelian groups $H^n(F^G)$, but how do we show that they are finitely generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F_n$ is a finitely-generated $G$-module, so it is also finitely-generated as a $\mathbf Z$-module because $\mathbf Z[G]$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbf Z$-module (since $G$ is finite).

Now $F_n^G$ is a subgroup of a finitely-generated abelian group, so it is also finitely-generated. Thus $H^n(F^G)$ is a subquotient of a finitely-generated abelian group, so it is also finitely-generated.

Comment: +1 I guess that a point worth emphasizing is that we can **choose** a resolution such that all the component modules $F_n$ are finitely generated. We could add infinite rank idle summands in there, if we wished. But why would we do that :-)

Comment: @Jared The Tate groups are defined for every $n\in \mathbf Z$, and they're a bit different for $n=0$ and $n=1$ (see Milne's notes on class field theory, for instance).

Comment: @Jyrki Indeed! We even have the "standard resolution", given to us for free! :)

Comment: @Jared, (just dropping in here) In that case they are equivalent.

Comment: @Jared: Ah, I see. I misunderstood what you had written! Good luck with your talk. :)