# Why are projective modules cohomologically trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, group-cohomology, projective-module

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H\subset G$ a subgroup, $k$ a commutative ring, $M$ a $kG$-module, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\hat{H}\,^n(H,M)$ the $n$th Tate cohomology group as defined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571294/finite-generation-of-tate-cohomology-groups), where we consider $M$ a $kH$-module via $kH\hookrightarrow kG$.

We say that $M$ is cohomologically trivial if $\hat{H}\,^n(H,M)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and all subgroups $H\subset G$.  Using Shapiro's lemma and the double coset formula, I can see that free $kG$-modules are cohomologically trivial.  I'd like to use this to conclude that projective $kG$-modules are also cohomologically trivial.

If $N$ is projective, then we can find $N'$ such that $N\oplus N'=M$ is free, and hence cohomologically trivial.  Then, the injection of $kG$-modules $N\hookrightarrow M$ gives a map of cohomology groups

$$\hat{H}\,^n(H,N)\to\hat{H}\,^n(H,M)=0$$

but unless this map is injective, we can't conclude that $N$ is cohomologically trivial.  Is this map injective, and if not, how can I show that projective modules are cohomologically trivial?  Perhaps I need to use the fact that $N$ is a direct summand of $M$, and not just a submodule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion of $N$ into $M$ has a section, that is, a map $M\to N$ whose composition with $N\to M$ is the identity of $N$. This and functoriality does what you want.

Comment: It is very false that cohomology with values in a *submodule* of a free module is zero. For example, the free module $kG$ of rank $1$ has the trivial module as submodule! (and this trivial submodule is a summand iff the group ring $kG$ is semisimple)

Comment: Ah yes.  Very nice.  Thank you, thank you.